# How to avoid long if else statements using RxJS

Tags: javascript, if-statement, rxjs, rxjs5

I'm trying to use RxJS to replace the next piece of code([jsbin](https://jsbin.com/lixudax/1/edit?html,js,console,output)):

```
function parseRequestUrl(url) {
  var newUrl;
  if ((newUrl = testThatUrlIsOrigin1(url)) !== url) {
    return doSomething(newUrl);
  }
  if ((newUrl = testThatUrlIsOrigin2(url)) !== url) {
    return doSomething(newUrl);
  }
  if ((newUrl = testThatUrlIsOrigin3(url)) !== url) {
    return doSomething(newUrl);
  }
}
```

Something i was able to achieve using RxJS([jsbin](https://jsbin.com/kaganet/1/edit?html,js,console,output)) but in that case i needed to call a function twice for which "filter expression" is true

```
function parseRequestUrl(url) {
  var newUrl = url;
  var observer = Rx.Observable.of(testThatUrlIsOrigin1, testThatUrlIsOrigin2, testThatUrlIsOrigin3);
  observer.first(getUrlFunc => getUrlFunc(url) !== url).map(getUrlFunc => getUrlFunc(url)).subscribe(createdUrl => newUrl = createdUrl)

  return doSomething(newUrl);
  // And so on
}
```

Can RxJS suit my requirements ?

Comment: Quote from Ben Lesh ( RxJS project lead) `Don't try to RxJS everything`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that RxJs is the right tool for the job. It is best suited for processing asynchronous streams of data. I think that a better approach would be to just put all of your test functions in an array and loop over them. Something like this:

```js
const tests = [testThatUrlIsOrigin1, testThatUrlIsOrigin2, testThatUrlIsOrigin3];
function parseRequestUrl(url) {
  for (const test of tests) {
    const newUrl = test(url);
    if (newUrl === url) continue;
    return newUrl;
  }
}
 
 
function testThatUrlIsOrigin1(url) {
 console.log("try testThatUrlIsOrigin1");
 if (url === 'origin1') {
      console.log("Pass testThatUrlIsOrigin1");
      return "First If";
  }
  return url;
}

function testThatUrlIsOrigin2(url) {
 console.log("try testThatUrlIsOrigin2");
 if (url === 'origin2') {
      console.log("Pass testThatUrlIsOrigin2");
     return "Second If";
    }
  return url;
}

function testThatUrlIsOrigin3(url) {
 console.log("try testThatUrlIsOrigin3");
 if (url === 'origin3') {
      console.log("Pass testThatUrlIsOrigin3");
      return "Third If";
    }
  return url;
}

parseRequestUrl('origin2')
```

You could also implement the [Chain of Responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) design pattern if you wanted to get all OO on it.

**EDIT**
Since you want to see how to do it in RxJs, here is a simplified version:

```js
function test(a, b) {
  return a === b ? `${a} test` : b;
}

const tests = [
  test.bind(null, 1),
  test.bind(null, 2),
  test.bind(null, 3),
];

const value = 2;
Rx.Observable.from(tests)
    .map(x => x(value))
    .filter(x => x !== value)
    .take(1)
    .subscribe(
      x => { console.log(x); },
      null,
      () => { console.log('completed'); }
    );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.5/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for response. Maybe my example does not explain what i want to understand, . For example we have chain of functions which are come one by one, and each function should decide either chain should be continued or interrupted and also we should be able get the result from this chain of the last executed function

Comment: @nikolayandr I believe that this code does what you described. It goes down the chain (array) of functions and evaluates each. If it fails then it continues down the chain but if it passes it returns the result. I assume that your functions are predefined, right?

Comment: Right. And yes i agree that in this case it is enough to use your suggestion.  But i really interested in getting information how to implement chain for described above case. If could help, it would be really cool. Spent 4 hours and still is stuck :)

Comment: @nikolayandr OK. I added an example with RxJs to satisfy your curiosity :)